# (PHP) fwrite doesn't write but overwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

I want to open the .xml file and write the content of the `$xml_doc` variable into the file. The problem is, when the file is empty, it refuses to write. It only writes when there is already some text (abc123 for example). I tried to change mode of fopen function to a, a+, w, w+, and w, w+ are simply erase the file content but write nothing.

```
if($telecharger) {
    // Creation du fichier
    $nom = "PRELEVEMENT";
    $filename= "/home/alc/alcg_si/alcgroup/intranet/documents/prelevement_xml/".$nom."__".$date_prev.".xml";
    try {
        $file = fopen($filename, 'r+') or die("Error: can't open file.");
        chmod($filename, 0777);

        fwrite($file, '$xml_doc') or die("Error: can\'t write in file.");
        fclose($file);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "MERDEEEE<br>";
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

Comment: What is `'$xml_doc'` ???

Comment: Are you getting an error using the code you posted?

Comment: @AbraCadaver $xml_doc is just a content. Even if i change the content to "123abc", it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dave I received the "Error: can\'t write in file" that i wrote. It didn't even go to exception.

Comment: A mode of `w` should certainly work given what you've shown us. What do you get if you use mode `w` instead of `r+`?

Comment: In w mode, i get an empty file, all the content pre-wrote is erased.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around `$xml_doc`. Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only in double quotes.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? That wasn't intended as the solution, it's an unrelated problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are checked when opening the file. If the file permissions don't allow writing, you need to call `chmod()` *before* calling `fopen()`.

You can also replace all the code that calls `fopen`, `fwrite`, and `fclose` with a single call to `file_put_contents()`.

And don't put the variable `$xml_doc` in single quotes, that prevents expanding the variable. It will write the literal string `$xml_doc` to the file.

```
if($telecharger) {
    // Creation du fichier
    $nom = "PRELEVEMENT";
    $filename= "/home/alc/alcg_si/alcgroup/intranet/documents/prelevement_xml/".$nom."__".$date_prev.".xml";
    try {
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            chmod($filename, 0644) or die("Error: can't change file permissions");
        }
        file_put_contents($filename, $xml_doc) or die("Error: can\'t write in file.");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "MERDEEEE<br>";
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

Comment: For the sake of setting a good example, I'd rather see `0664` there in place of `0777`!

Comment: @Barmar The file had not been created so it could not change the file mode, `Error: can't change file permissions` at the first place.

Comment: I've added a check for whether the file exists before trying to change permissions. Also, do you have write permission to the directory? You won't be able to create a new file there if you don't.

Comment: @Barmar The permission of the directory is also 777.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled? If any of the functions fails there should be a warning message saying what went wrong.